# URLDownloadToFile always return S_OK

Tags: c++, winapi, url, download, wininet

I'm new to c++ and try to write a update function.

The download with URLDownloadToFile is working without problems but if I changed the url to an invalid one, it stilled return S_OK ... How can I check if the download succede or not?

```
#include <WinInet.h>
#include <iomanip> 

int download_file (const TCHAR urldownload[],const TCHAR target[] )
{
    DownloadProgress progress;
    IBindStatusCallback* callback = (IBindStatusCallback*)&progress;

    SCP(40, NULL); cout << target;

    HRESULT status = URLDownloadToFile(NULL, urldownload, target, 0, static_cast<IBindStatusCallback*>(&progress));
    Sleep(200);
    DeleteUrlCacheEntry(urldownload);

    wcout << status;

    if (status == S_OK) cout << "yes";
    else(cout << "Download failed");

    Sleep(10000); return 1;
}


class DownloadProgress : public IBindStatusCallback {
public:
HRESULT __stdcall QueryInterface(const IID &, void **) {
    return E_NOINTERFACE;
}
ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef(void) {
    return 1;
}
ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release(void) {
    return 1;
}
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnStartBinding(DWORD dwReserved, IBinding *pib) {
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetPriority(LONG *pnPriority) {
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnLowResource(DWORD reserved) {
    return S_OK;
}
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnStopBinding(HRESULT hresult, LPCWSTR szError) {
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetBindInfo(DWORD *grfBINDF, BINDINFO *pbindinfo) {
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnDataAvailable(DWORD grfBSCF, DWORD dwSize, FORMATETC *pformatetc, STGMEDIUM *pstgmed) {
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnObjectAvailable(REFIID riid, IUnknown *punk) {
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

virtual HRESULT __stdcall OnProgress(ULONG ulProgress, ULONG ulProgressMax, ULONG ulStatusCode, LPCWSTR szStatusText)
{
    //wcout << ulProgress << L" of " << ulProgressMax << endl; Sleep(200);
    if (ulProgress != 0 && ulProgressMax != 0)
    {
        double output = (double(ulProgress) / ulProgressMax)*100;
        cout << "\r" << "Downloading: " << fixed << setprecision(2) << output << " %  " ; Sleep(20);
    }
    return S_OK;
}
};
```

Comment: That's not standard c++. Which framework/library are you using?

Comment: Iam using  <WinInet.h>  <iomanip>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN article has the answer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123) for you:

> `URLDownloadToFile` returns `S_OK` even if the file cannot be created and the download is canceled. If the szFileName parameter contains a file path, ensure that the destination directory exists before calling `URLDownloadToFile`. For best control over the download and its progress, **an `IBindStatusCallback` interface is recommended**.

You need to provide a status callback to receive status of the asynchronous operation. Your code snippet already has the base. `OnProgress` and `OnStopBinding` should get you the download failure result.

Comment: oh well, thx I didnt read that line before -.-...

Iam using the IBindStatusCallback, used a code sniped for that cause I dont understand how that class is working... so Iam still stucked and that point.. is there no simple way to send the call back to my void update() function?

Comment: Trace every call of status callback to `cout` and you will get the idea.

Comment: could you give me an expample? I cant figure it out : /

Comment: You already have code for it. What exactly is the problem you are having with it? Please update your question with more details.

Comment: @Zerray: You may think that you are using an `IBindStatusCallback` interface. However, your implementation of `QueryInterface` returns `E_NOINTERFACE`. Consequently, `URLDownloadToFile` is likely to disagree that what you passed in actually is the required `IBindStatusCallback`. You may want read [Introduction to COM and ATL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/727z646z.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "wininet.h"

DeleteUrlCacheEntry((LPCSTR)url);
HRESULT response = URLDownloadToFile(NULL, (LPCSTR)url, (LPCSTR)default_path, 0, NULL);
```

I hope this works